# Avoiding Looping Through Every row and column

Tags: r, xts

I came across this function a while back that was created for fixing PCA values. The problem with the function was that it wasn't compatible xts time series objects.

```
amend <- function(result) {
  result.m <- as.matrix(result)
  n <- dim(result.m)[1]
  delta <- apply(abs(result.m[-1,] - result.m[-n,]), 1, sum)
  delta.1 <- apply(abs(result.m[-1,] + result.m[-n,]), 1, sum)
  signs <- c(1, cumprod(rep(-1, n-1) ^ (delta.1 <= delta)))
  zoo(result * signs)
}
```

Full sample can be found https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/im-getting-jumpy-loadings-in-rollapply-pca-in-r-can-i-fix-it

The problem is that applying the function on a xts object with multiple columns and rows wont solve the problem. Is there a elegant way of applying the algorithm for a matrix of xts objects?

My current solution given a single column with multiple row is to loop through row by row...which is slow and tedious. Imagine having to do it column by column also.

Thanks,

Here is some code to get one started:

```
rm(list=ls())
require(RCurl)
sit = getURLContent('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz',         binary=TRUE, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
con = gzcon(rawConnection(sit, 'rb'))
source(con)
close(con)
load.packages('quantmod')


data <- new.env()

tickers<-spl("VTI,IEF,VNQ,TLT")
getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '1980-01-01', env = data, auto.assign = T)
for(i in ls(data)) data[[i]] = adjustOHLC(data[[i]], use.Adjusted=T)

bt.prep(data, align='remove.na', dates='1990::2013')

prices<-data$prices[,-10]  #don't include cash
retmat<-na.omit(prices/mlag(prices) - 1)


rollapply(retmat, 500, function(x) summary(princomp(x))$loadings[, 1], by.column = FALSE, align = "right") -> princomproll

require(lattice)
xyplot(amend(pruncomproll))
```

plotting "princomproll" will get you jumpy loadings...

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very obvious how the `amend` function relates to the script below it (since it isn't called there), or what you are trying to achieve.  There are a couple of small changes that can be made.  I haven't profiled the difference, but it's a little more readable if nothing else.

1. You remove the first and last rows of the result twice.
2. `rowSums` might be slightly more efficient for getting the row sums than `apply`.
3. `rep.int` is a little bit fster than `rep`.

---

```
amend <- function(result) {
  result <- as.matrix(result)
  n <- nrow(result)
  without_first_row <- result[-1,]
  without_last_row <- result[-n,]
  delta_minus <- rowSums(abs(without_first_row - without_last_row))
  delta_plus <- rowSums(abs(without_first_row + without_last_row))
  signs <- c(1, cumprod(rep.int(-1, n-1) ^ (delta_plus <= delta_minus)))
  zoo(result * signs)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, I am trying to fix my pca time series loading which is very jumpy. The problem with the function is that it doesn't accept a xts object which renders it very inefficient if I were to manually loop over it. In the stack overflow page, the coder who made this function provides a full sample. I didn't want to copy the entire answer over. I tried to loop but when my xts object has many columns this will be slow.